# Existence of additive measure of an arbitrary set on its sigma-algebra?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory

In Folland we sort of define what it mean to be a measure and then develop outer measure, Lebesgue measure, etc. based on given measure. However, there is no such theorem that says such measure exist for an arbitrary set, without specifying what the set will be (can be countable, uncountable, finite, etc.). Is measure theory itself axiomatic? Or is there actually a way to construct such measure?

**note:**

Countable additivity must be satisfied: 
$$\mu(\cup A_j)=\sum_j\mu(A_j)$$for disjoint sequence $\{A_j\}$

Comment: For any set $X$, define the measure $\mu$ on the $\sigma$ field $\{X,\emptyset\}$ as $\mu X = 1, \mu \emptyset = 0$. A measure is defined by a collection of axioms which can be easily found by Googling same.

Comment: For any non-empty set $X$ and any $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma$ on $X$, we can define the following measure on $(X,\Sigma)$: Let $a\in X$ (there is such $a$ because $X$ is non-empty) . Define for any $E\in \Sigma$ , $\mu(E)=1$ if $a\in E$ and $\mu(E)= 0$ if $a \notin E$. It is easy to prove that $\mu$ is a measure.